# Looking for baseline GIS software

Tags: c#, gis, wpf

I'm looking for a C# GIS app, preferably one that can be used easily with WPF, that does some if not all of the following:

- Layered GIS with world shoreline representation, zoom, etc
- Selectable display of layers
- Import and display of standard charts (ie coastlines, shipping lanes, etc)
- Project save/load
- polygon creation and modification
- mensuration
- annotation

This will be ran on Windows. A free app is preferable, but cost shouldn't be an issue if it isn't.

Looking for something that can be extended if it doesn't match all the requirements above.

I have tried SharpMap and GreatMaps (GMap.NET) so far and would like a few more options so I can conduct a trade study.

Comment: be worth checking this discussion: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22326/are-there-any-decent-free-gis-projects-built-in-c-or-with-a-good-c-api

Comment: I'll have to check out MapWindow, haven't heard of that before.